# XMLSpy in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, qtp, xmlspy

I need to test XMLSpy functionality in Eclipse. After I switch Eclipse to XMLSpy Perspective and QTP is runnig (record or run mode), it does not work. Could you help me?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[**Altova** support](https://www.altova.com/search?q=%22quick%20test%22) does not seem to have any reference including "Quik Test Pro" issues.

However, check for other plugins (other than XmlSpy):
[similar tools has been known to fail in interaction with TPTP](https://web.archive.org/web/20061118185053/http://dev.eclipse.org:80/mhonarc/lists/tptp-testing-tools-dev/msg00329.html) for instance.

Check also your Error log view, and complete your question with error messages displayed at the time of the recording.

[image]
<sub>(source: [eclipse.org](http://help.eclipse.org/help32/topic/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/guide/images/views/error_log.png))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Some more information would be helpful.  "It does not work" is extremely vague.  What does  not work?  Do you mean that QTP does not record anything at all?  Do you mean that QTP records something, but it is incorrect?  Does it record some of your test, but misses one particular control, such as a grid?  Do you have the right QTP add-ins/plugins enabled to support automation with Eclipse?